# Cracked laptop lcd screen with gray spots appearing

Tags: laptop, lcd

I have opened my pavilion HDX 18 laptop to replace the screen backlight (one of the lamps broke but there were no gray spots). Once I put it back together The screen appeared cracked and it displayed gray large spots around it. From day to day the spots change in size and some of them are opaque and others are semi transparents. Some of them can even disappear. They appear to be comming out of the crack and can be anywhere from small to large.

**keep in mind that my crack did not appear after i dropped my laptop but after i opened it to change the backlight that broke (at least most Likely because i couldn't fully see the crack till i turned on my computer with the new backlight)**

What exactly is wrong with my screen?
Is it easy to fix or do I need to replace the whole screen?

I noticed that the screen is composed of multiple sheets and I think it might be just one of the sheets that broke and I can replace just that. (they are very thin and I think I just ripped it while opening the backlight)

Ill supply an image as soon as I am able to

OK this is not exactly how it looks like on my laptop its much better and my spots are mostly transparent-gray but its something similar  to this image:

[image: similar crack cellphone]

Comment: no there appears to be no bubbles in the screen. Also why would anyone give this question a negative vote.

Comment: nono im not accusing you. I am just wondering why would anybody give it a negative vote i feel like its an excellent question and i did a lot of research and i couldnt find an answer. When i turn the computer off you can still see the crack and there are probably still gray spots but you cant see them since the computer is dark.

Comment: I am asking because i might want to fix the computer myself i did that many times before! why would i spend tons of money for some guy to replace one part.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but I'm pretty sure that your question is not clear for all. `1:` Why did you replace your screen? was that break? `2:` Is you new LCD broken at the time of replacing?

Comment: It sounds to be as if your new screen was broken when you got it, or in the installation process. See if you can return it and get another.

Comment: I was replacing the screen backlight not the screen (the lamps that lit the screen because one of them broke)

Comment: Then you broke the screen, it needs replaced.

Comment: Can you post a link to the image so we can add it for you?